# Firebase admin auth listAllUsers give - failed to determine project ID

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

Using Node - v12.16.1
React + Firebase

```
this.adminSDK = admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
databaseURL: "https://APP_NAME.firebaseio.com"
});
console.log(this.adminSDK.name); //gives [DEFAULT]

//code below gives error
admin
.auth()
.listUsers()
.then(function (listUsersResult) {
  this.listOFUsers = listUsersResult;
  })
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log("Error listing users:", error);
 });
```

adminSDK.name gives = [DEFAULT] in console

listALLUsers gives error :

```
Error listing users: Error: Failed to determine project ID: Error while making request: Failed to fetch. Error code: undefined
    at FirebaseAppError.FirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js:42)
    at FirebaseAppError.PrefixedFirebaseError [as constructor] (error.js:88)
    at new FirebaseAppError (error.js:123)
    at credential.js:183
```

I have set "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"
Tried using SERVICE ACCOUNT credential method to initialize adminSDK, which gives Z_DATA error

Comment: It looks like your service account json file is invalid or corrupted. Can you check if it contains the `project_id`, `private_key` and `client_email` fields?

Comment: @HiranyaJayathilaka Providing my service json. PLease have a look.
{
  "type": "
  "project_id": "
  "private_key_id": "",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY----------END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "
  "client_id": 
  "auth_uri": "
  "token_uri": 
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": 
  "client_x509_cert_url":

Comment: That looks correct. If your `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` environment variable contains the path to that file, then everything should work without issues.

Comment: Figured it out. For anyone facing the same error: 
I was running this on Client side server. Fix - Run on server and fetch response from API (I used Firebase cloud functions to deploy API)
@HiranyaJayathilaka Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone facing the same error: I was running this on Client side server. Fix - Run on server and fetch response from API (I used Firebase cloud functions to deploy API)